# How to split 1 ethernet cable into 2 without a switch or splitter

Tags: ethernet, splitter

kind of an odd situation I am trying to figure out. This isn't your typical type of network with an ethernet cable split into 2 and I am aware of the use of a splitter and or switch but neither of those solutions will work in this case. Please help if you can or tell me if this will work.

Basically I have a computer that is installed in a vehicle. This computer has 4 ethernet pins dedicated to RX+, RX-, TX+ & TX-. The use of these 4 pins are to wire in an ethernet cable so the device can be plugged into a PC or laptop to be able to access the firmware and transmit / receive data.

What I am trying to do, is have the option of still having the ethernet cable to be able to plug it into the laptop, but at the same time the car will have a wifi router installed so a connection to the vehicle computer can be made from the PC without the need of plugging directly in and having a wireless connection.

Is it possible to splice each of the individual ethernet pins on the vehicle computer into 2? So 1 ethernet cable will go to the router, the other will be plugged into the laptop. I should also mention that nether cables will be used at the same time ever. The router will only ever be switched on when a wireless connection is needed and also the connection to the laptop PC will rarely need to be used. The wire going to the router will also be in a very tight location hard to reach so it will not be as simple as just using the same cable for the laptop and plugging it into the router and vice versa.

I think this will work, but I cant seem to find the answers anywhere as its not your typical type of ethernet network. Hopefully it makes sense what Im trying to do and somebody can help with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: *"I am aware of the use of a splitter and or switch but neither of those solutions will work in this case."* -- Why do you think a switch *"will not work"*?

Comment: Its not that a switch won't work, but since this is installed in a vehicle, there is no additional room available to install a switch and trying to keep this as simple as possible without adding any other equipment.

Comment: As I understand it you want to make an 'Y' split? If it's guaranteed that only one device will be connected at a time on the "split" end, then I guess this is more of an electronics.se question -- whether the unused fork will significantly degrade the signal or not.

Comment: Run two cables from the two hard toreach devices to a common location and use a joiner , search for Ethernet coupler,or plug it into the laptop.

Comment: @user1686 yes exactly. Only one device will ever be used at a time and thats what I am trying to figure out. We are talking a very short distance as well, the length of cable from the ECU to the router will be around 8 inches and the main cable to plug into the laptop will be closer to 8 feet. Thanks.

Comment: @Ross The router will be permanently mounted in the vehicle next to the ECU and needs to be plugged in at all times. I'm trying to avoid the need to have to plug in and switch different cables between the 2 devices. The router will be controlled by an On/Off switch and only ever used when the main cable isn't plugged into the laptop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well , you can try , but the extra wire can cause interference.  From a simplistic resistive circuit point of view, sure it looks fine, but it is a high frequency circuit.    With  inductance and it’ll act like an antenna I wouldn’t do it.  I'd just run two cables still its probably only 10meg so yes personally I'd find it hard to join the wires so I'd buy a coupler  which will take one rj45 in and connect two in parallel don’t get the splitters these take 8cores and put 4 to one out and 4 to the other.
I have both so I know they exist

Comment: These 8-to-2x4 splitters are meant to be used as a pair, and would require two physical ports on the router's side. OP wants to use just one port, switching it between two devices. But now that you mention it, I think I have also seen similar splitter-like things with a physical switch to choose between one "output" or another? ([Found an example.](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Portable-2-Port-RJ45-LAN-Network-Switch-Key-Press-Button-Selector-Standalone-Hub/222821886910))

Comment: yes 8 to 2 by 4 is not the one to use you can also get an 8 to 2 by 8 which is the one needed  as I said I have both

Comment: Right, I've misread your post.

Comment: Really didn’t think interference would be an issue? Would it not make a difference if the 1 branch going to the router is only 8” long and also if the router isn’t switched the opposite branch would be ok? The other branch will also be used with an panel mounted extension plug, that said if the extension cable isn’t plugged in which it wouldn’t be if the option to use the router is selected, that length of cable would only be around 15” these are both very short lengths, not sure if that matters. Also there is no physical rj45 socket on the ecu, just the 4 pins I first mentioned.

Comment: cars are very good emitter